# How can I get the current bundle name inside browserify's postBundleCB() method?

Tags: gruntjs, browserify

I would like to know the bundle's filepath, so I can clean up the script's base-path in debug sourcemaps.

But there doesn't seem to be any way of getting the current file's name?

```
postBundleCB: (err: string, src: Buffer, next: (err: string, modifiedSrc: Buffer) => void) => {
   var currentBundleFilePath = ???
   next(err, modifiedSrc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `package` event gets you a little further because it allows you to access `pkg.__dirname`. See https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/readme.markdown#bonpackage-function-pkg-